# How to save order of tabs to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, tabs, tabbar

I have 8 tabs and am using customizable tabBarItems. So the user can reorder the tabs. Now my question is how do I get the order of the tabs and save that to NSUserDefaults so it remains the same whenever the user exits the app and comes back.

Here is the code I've got so far:

`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didEndCustomizingItems:(NSArray *)items changed:(BOOL)changed {
    NSMutableArray *savedOrder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    NSArray *tabOrderToSave = tabBarController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *aViewController in tabOrderToSave) {
        [savedOrder addObject:aViewController.title];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedOrder forKey:@"savedTabOrder"];
}`

No errors in that code, it just doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way: My app is a tabBarApplication.

EDIT:
Here is what I've done.

Created a tabBar Application
Populated Views with data
Added 8 tabs with different views loaded from controllers
Then added the customizable reordering of tabs
Added the code above to save the tab order

Have do I retrieve that saved data when I relaunch the app?

EDIT 2:

I've been searching around and found a lot of info on this but very little on how.

Here is the code I have now:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
    NSMutableArray *vcArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
    NSArray *savedViews = tabBarController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *theVC in savedViews){
        [vcArray addObject:theVC.title];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:vcArray forKey:@"tabLayout"];
}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didEndCustomizingItems:(NSArray *)items changed:(BOOL)changed {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *tabLayout = [defaults arrayForKey:@"tabLayout"];
    NSMutableArray *orderedLayout = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
    NSArray *defaultOrder = tabBarController.viewControllers;

    for (int i =0; i < 6; i++){
        for (UIViewController *theVC in defaultOrder) {
            if ([theVC.title isEqualToString:[tabLayout objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                [orderedLayout addObject:theVC];
            }
        }
    }

    tabBarController.viewControllers = orderedLayout;
}
```

Why doesn't this work, and by that I mean after I customize the tabbar and hit stop in Xcode, when I go to run it again it doesn't show my saved order. What in the world am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: What doesn't work? How do you detect this?

Comment: @Nekto I launch the app in the simulator, reorder the tabs and quit. Then I relaunch the app and the tabs default back to the way they was before I reordered them.

Does this reorder behavior not work int the simulator?

Comment: And how do you load views when starting the app? Post more code..

Comment: it should work in the simulator as well.

Comment: @TheHAWK .. post the code which you use to load the tabbar again

Comment: What do you mean @Saurabh. The code I posted is in the AppDelegate.m file.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the synchronize.
Try this:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didEndCustomizingItems:(NSArray *)items changed:(BOOL)changed {
    NSMutableArray *savedOrder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    NSArray *tabOrderToSave = tabBarController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *aViewController in tabOrderToSave) {
        [savedOrder addObject:aViewController.title];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedOrder forKey:@"savedTabOrder"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standarduserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Nekto said - What doesn't work? How do you detect this?

also saving this info won't save your tabbar order... you have to fetch this order from nsuserdefault and generate the tab in that order next time ..

Comment: It doesn't save the order! 

How do I fetch the order @Saurabh? 

@Nekto I load view with the nib, I just set it to the xib controller class and the view loads up fine.

Comment: What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: @TheHAK - if you are using nib (xib) for generating your tabbarcontroller's view you can't accomplish this. ..  you have to generate your view using coding.. you need to fetch tab order from nsuserdefaults and generate tabs in the same order

Comment: I'm using code to generate the tabBar and the view. How do I fetch the tab order from NSUserDefaults and generate tabs in the same order?

Comment: I added some info to my original post. Is everything clear now?

Comment: After searching around, I have added the code I am having problems with now. Can anyone take a look and tell me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I've been using

```
-(void) saveTabOrder
{

    NSMutableArray *savedOrder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
    NSArray *tabOrderToSave    =   tabBarController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *aViewController in tabOrderToSave) 
    {
        [savedOrder addObject:aViewController.title];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedOrder forKey:@"savedTabOrder"];
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

// NOTE -- because tabs may change between versions of the app,
// should NOT try to restore tabs if the tab count or names
// differ from the saved version.

```
- (void)setTabOrderIfSaved {
    //return;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *savedOrder = [defaults arrayForKey:@"savedTabOrder"];
    NSMutableArray *orderedTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];

    if ([savedOrder count] > 0 )     
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < [savedOrder count]; i++)  // loop through saved tabs
        {
            BOOL tabFound = NO;
            for (UIViewController *aController in tabBarController.viewControllers) // loop through actual tabs
            {
                if ([aController.title isEqualToString:[savedOrder objectAtIndex:i]]) 
                {
                    [orderedTabs addObject:aController];
                    tabFound = YES;
                }
            }
            if (!tabFound) 
            {
                // so the old tab order doesn't include this tab.  Lets bail and use the default ordering
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"savedTabOrder"];
                return;
            }
        }
        tabBarController.viewControllers = orderedTabs;
    }

}
```

Comment: PS -- NEVER hit "stop" in the simulator without first clicking on the round home button to have the simulator shut down the app.  There is important housekeeping (like synchronizing defaults) that you want to happen.